# How to change your app's target API using flash CS6

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, sdk, google-play, flash-cs6

I tried uploading APK to google play but get this error:

Your app currently targets API level 21 and must target at least API level 26 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 26

How would one change the API level in Flash CS6?

Comment: So if you really insist on using CS6 you may need to manually download and place the SDK in the folder within the CS6's installation directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify an Android target SDK for your Adobe AIR Android application you need to add the `uses-sdk` node to your manifest additions in your application descriptor.

You can add any of the values below. Normally we specify a target and a minimum version in our applications (however you can also add a `maxSdkVersion` option if you need it).

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">

            <uses-sdk 
                android:minSdkVersion="19"
                android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

            <!-- OTHER MANIFEST ADDITIONS -->

         </manifest>
    ]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

Answer (score 1):

First download the SDK version you wish to use from [adobe.com](https://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html), then extract the sdk zip somewhere, and finally select **Help** > **Manage AIR SDK...** from Flash CS6, and click plus icon to add a new sdk path.

Comment: hello, so I tried doing this but every SDK past like 24 or 25 i get this error when I try publishing

Comment: dx tool failed:Cannot create java virtual machine.                          do you know how to get this error fixed so I can try a higher SDK?

Comment: Can't be sure, but you could try installing different versions of Java, and maybe raising memory limit in jvm.ini

Comment: so if I manage to get the java virtual machine error to go away.. the new AIR SDK would in theory make my API higher? And is this the only way? Maybe there is a way to target an API through the app XML file? thanks

Comment: When you add new SDKs, you get new options for AIR Target in Publish Settings, and changing the option modifies also the XML.

Comment: thanks for the information. I guess if you get the latest SDK it will modify the target API automatically. In this case where I cannot use a higher SDK (due to errors) adding the code Micheal provided above made it work on an older SDK.