# Using Adobe Animate CC to publish app with API 26 target, but get error message from Google Play Console that target is API 24

Tags: actionscript-3, jquery-animate, adobe

I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I am trying to upload my apk file thru Google Play Console. I keep getting the error message, " Upload failed Your app currently targets API level 24 and must target at least API level 26 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 26." even though my target for the project in Adobe Animate CC says, "AIR 26 for Android".

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51716709/4756930)?

Answer (score 2):

The AIR SDK version is different from the Android SDK version. The version numbers appear similar but are not the same.

In order to specify v26 as the target SDK, add the following to your manifest additions:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
```

The AIR SDK contains a particular version of the Android build tools which is used as the default target sdk if you don't specify anything different in the manifest.

**I believe to target Android SDK v26 you will need to be using at least AIR SDK v29.**